# How to set Vue child component object from parent

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm fairly new to Vue and am working with the Vue 3 composition api.  I'm also using Vuetify, so the dialog is code copied from their example.  Hopefully I haven't made it more complicated by mixing that into my learning.  I have a main list of users populated currently by a javascript array.  The idea is a fairly common set up where it lists each user in the array and the user's link opens a dialog to edit the user info.  There's also an Add User link to open the dialog to add a user.

In my code, so far, I can get the dialog to open when I click a name.  I can't get it to open when clicking the Add User link.  They both call the same method, but the Add User link simply passes null for the value of user.  When clicking the link for a user, although the dialog opens, it doesn't set the property of the user to populate the form.  So, I've got a couple of issues.  How to open the dialog from the Add User link, and how to populate the user from the user link.  The basic code is below.

store.js

```
import { reactive } from 'vue'

class Store{
    constructor() {
        this.state = reactive({
            users: [
                { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Smithers" },
                { id: 2, firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Smithers"}
            ],
            currentUserId: null
        })
    }
    
    addUser(){
        this.state.currentUserId = null;
    }
}

export const store = new Store()
```

UserList.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import {store} from '../services/store.js'
import UserForm from './UserForm.vue'

const userform = ref(null)
const openDialog = (user) => {
  userform.user = user
  userform.value.openDialog()
}
</script>

<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Users</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="user in store.state.users" :key="user.id">
      <td><a href="javascript:;" @click="openDialog(user)">{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="text-center" style="padding:20px 0">
        <a href="javascript:;" @onclick="openDialog(null)">Add User</a>
        <UserForm user="null" ref="userform"></UserForm>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</template>
```

UserForm.vue

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'

const dialog = ref(false)
const save = () => {
  console.log('saving')
}
const openDialog =() => {
  dialog.value = true;
}
const props = defineProps({
  user: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
  },
  openDialog: {
    type: Boolean
  }
})

const emits = defineEmits(['save'])
defineExpose({
  openDialog
});

</script>

<template>
  <form>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-dialog
          v-model="dialog"
          persistent
          width="1024"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="text-h5">Add a User</span>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-container>
              <v-row>

                <v-col cols="12" lg="4" sm="4" xs="12">
                  <v-text-field
                      label="First name*"
                      required
                      v-model="props.user.firstName"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>

                <v-col cols="12" lg="4" sm="4" xs="12">
                  <v-text-field
                      label="Middle name"
                      hint="example of helper text only on focus"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>

                <v-col cols="12" lg="4" sm="4" xs="12">
                  <v-text-field
                      label="Last name"
                      hint="example of helper text only on focus"
                      v-model="props.user.lastName"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                
              </v-row>  
                
              <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" lg="6" sm="6" xs="12">
                  <v-text-field
                      label="Email*"
                      required
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" lg="6" sm="6" xs="12">
                  <v-text-field
                      label="Password*"
                      type="password"
                      required
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
              
              
              <v-row>
                <v-col
                    cols="12"
                    sm="6"
                >
                  <v-select
                      :items="['0-17', '18-29', '30-54', '54+']"
                      label="Age*"
                      required
                  ></v-select>
                </v-col>
                <v-col
                    cols="12"
                    sm="6"
                >
                  <v-autocomplete
                      :items="['Skiing', 'Ice hockey', 'Soccer', 'Basketball', 'Hockey', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Coding', 'Basejump']"
                      label="Interests"
                      multiple
                  ></v-autocomplete>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-container>
            <small>*indicates required field</small>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
                color="blue-darken-1"
                variant="text"
                @click="dialog = false"
            >
              Close
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
                class="ma-2"
                color="primary"
                @click="save"
            >
              <v-icon
                  start
                  icon="mdi-checkbox-marked-circle"
              ></v-icon>
              Save
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-row>
  </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by this line:

```
userform.user = user
```

since userform is a ref, and so userform.user doesn't parse for me.

One possible solution is to pass an empty dummy user into the dialog component, e.g.,

```js
const selectedUser = ref(null);
const dialog = ref(false);  
const openDialog = (user) => {
  if (user) {
    selectedUser.value = user;
  } else {
    selectedUser.value = {
      id: store.state.users.length + 1,
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
     }
  }
  dialog.value = true;
}
```

The whole thing could look like:

## UserList.vue:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card width="800" class="ml-4 mt-4">
        <v-card-title>
          Users
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-table class="w-auto">
            <thead>
              <tr class="bg-grey-lighten-3">
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="user in store.state.users" :key=user.id>
                <td><a href="#" @click.prevent="openDialog(user)">{{ user.firstName }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" @click.prevent="openDialog(user)">{{ user.lastName }}</a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </v-table>          
        </v-card-text>

      </v-card>        
      <v-btn 
                rounded="lg"
        color="primary"
                class="mt-4 ml-4"
                @click="openDialog(null)">Add User</v-btn>
      <my-dialog v-model:dialog="dialog" :user="selectedUser" @save="saveUser"/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import {store} from './store.js'
import MyDialog from './MyDialog.vue';
  
const selectedUser = ref(null);
const dialog = ref(false);  
const openDialog = (user) => {
  if (user) {
    selectedUser.value = user;
  } else {
    selectedUser.value = {
      // get max user id and add 1
      id: Math.max(...store.state.users.map(o => o.id)) + 1,
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    }
  }
  dialog.value = true;
}  
const saveUser = (user) => {
  let existingUser = store.state.users.find((u) => u.id === user.id);
  if (existingUser) {
    existingUser.lastName = user.lastName;
    existingUser.firstName = user.firstName;
  } else {
    store.state.users.push(user);    
  }
}
</script>
```

## MyDialog.vue:

```html
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-dialog
      :model-value="dialog"
      persistent
    >
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="text-h5">User Profile</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container>
            <v-row>
              <v-col
                                cols="4"
              >
                <v-text-field
                  label="Legal first name*"
                                    v-model="first"  
                                    @keyup.enter="saveUser"                              
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col
                                cols="4"
              >
                <v-text-field
                  label="Legal last name*"
                  hint="example of persistent helper text"
                                    v-model="last"
                                    @keyup.enter="saveUser"                              
                                    persistent-hint
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
          <small>*indicates required field</small>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            color="blue-darken-1"
            variant="text"
            @click="closeDialog"
          >
            Close
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn
            color="blue-darken-1"
            variant="text"
            @click="saveUser"
          >
            Save
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch, onMounted } from 'vue';
const props =  defineProps(['user', 'dialog']);
const emit = defineEmits(['update:dialog', 'save']);
const first = ref("");
const last = ref("");
  
const closeDialog = () => {
  emit("update:dialog", false);
}  

const saveUser = () => {
  let user = {
    id: props.user.id,
    firstName: first.value,
    lastName: last.value,
  }
  emit("save", user);
  emit("update:dialog", false);
}

watch(() => props.dialog, 
  (newValue) => {
    if (newValue) {
      first.value = props.user.firstName;
      last.value = props.user.lastName;
    }
});
</script>
```

## store.js

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

class Store{
    constructor() {
        this.state = reactive({
            users: [
                { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Smithers" },
                { id: 2, firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Smithers"}
            ],
            currentUserId: null
        })
    }
    
    addUser(){
        this.state.currentUserId = null;
    }
}

export const store = new Store()
```

Code may be found on the [Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

---

Option is to allow the dialog to accept a null user and deal with it.

To allow the above code to work with this, I test for the truthiness of `props.user` when the dialog is opened, when `props.dialog` turns true:

```js
watch(() => props.dialog, 
  (newValue) => {
    if (newValue) {
      if (props.user) {
        first.value = props.user.firstName;
        last.value = props.user.lastName;
      } else {
        first.value = "";
        last.value = "";
      }      
    }
});
```

[Vuetify Playground for the "null" option](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thank you.  Now I just need to work through this and make sure I understand how it works.

Comment: @geoffswartz: I'm sure that there are other ways to solve this, but this is what I came up with. Note changes just now made.

Comment: @geoffswartz: Also, the above code can be found on the Vuetify Playground. This is what I had to use to try to come up with something since I do not use Vuetify (until now).